# How to convert c# code to vb.net. Error occurred in getting numeric value of a character

Tags: c#, vb.net, ascii

I am trying to convert the c# project into vb.net project. But i am not able to convert some code in vb.net.

C# Code:

```
if ((a >= 33) && (a <= 48)) { word += "|"; word1 += "|"; }
```

Vb.net Code:

```
If (Char.GetNumericValue(a) >= 33) AndAlso (Char.GetNumericValue(a) <= 48) Then
    word += "|"
    word1 += "|"
End If
```

Here in c# the numeric value of a is directly compared with integer value. But in Vb.net i can't get the numeric value of a to compare with the ASCII value. If there is any possible to convert the c# project solution into vb.net solution? Let me know the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to use `Asc(a)`?

Comment: That should be `Convert.ToInt32`. If you read the documentation for `Char.GetNumericValue` it should be obvious why that is not what you want.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov Yeah I tested using Asc(a) also. While using this Asc(a) am getting the value as same integer value for all character

Comment: @jmcilhinney Now it works by using `Convert.ToInt32`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert a character value into its ASC value and then compare it with a value in vb.net find sample code as below

```
Dim a As Char
a = "a"
Dim i As Integer = Asc(a)
Console.Write(i.ToString())
If i < 90 Then
    'Do what you want
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the VB 'AscW' function (not 'Asc'), assuming that 'a' is a char:

```
If (AscW(a) >= 33) AndAlso (AscW(a) <= 48) Then
    word &= "|"
    word1 &= "|"
End If
```